# .Net Core Web API - How Do I Populate a DTO That Contains a Generic List

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, data-transfer-objects

My datamodel consists of a 1 to many relationship between an Employee table and a Projects table. I need my DTO to return an Employee object that contains a collection/list of Project objects. I am using a repository pattern to return data from the database. Question 1: How do I populate the List property of the DTO?  Question 2: Is my approach a correct one?  Question 3: I am returning the list of Project objects as an IEnumerable. Should the Projects property in my DTO be a List, IList, Collection?  Here is my code. Thank you in advance.

```
//My DTO
public class EmployeeReadDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

//GetAll signature from my generic repository
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()

//Controller where I am trying to populate DTO
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "employee/GetById")]
public ActionResult<EmployeeReadDto> GetById(int id)
{
    var projects = _projectRep.GetAll();
    var employee = _employeeRep.GetById(id);

    var dto = new EmployeeReadDto
    {
        Id = employee.Id,
        FName = employee.FName,
        LName = employee.LName,
        Email = employee.Email,
        Projects = projects
    };

    return Ok(dto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: How do I populate the List property of the DTO? Question
> 2: Is my approach a correct one? Question 3: I am returning the list
> of Project objects as an IEnumerable. Should the Projects property in
> my DTO be a List, IList, Collection?

- `IEnumerable<T>` implements the IEnumerable interface method to improve
  the collection that can be iterated.
- `ICollection<T>` inherits both IEnumerable and IEnumerable
  interfaces.
- `IList` inherits the IEnumerable and ICollection interfaces.
- `List` is a class, which not only implements their interface, but also
  extends more methods.

So, returning the list of Project objects as an IEnumerable is not correct, but it can be returned as `List, IList, ICollection`.

Try change your code as follow:

```
public List<T> GetAll()
```